# SA-MP servers crashes at start

Tags: linux, crash, pawn, sa-mp

I have a server for almost 4 years and I didn't have any problems (host side) until now. I changed hostings all the time because ddos stuff trying to find best for me. Now I buyed one VPS (its not my first) and tried to run my server and i have problem with it.

First here is my server.cfg:

```
echo Executing Server Config...
lanmode 0

rcon_password werwesfsdfsd
maxplayers 50
port 7777
hostname samp server
gamemode0 emskp
filterscripts map1 map2 map3 houses events actors
plugins sql.so regex.so sscanf.so streamer.so
announce 0
query 1
weburl www.sa-mp.com
maxnpc 0
onfoot_rate 40
incar_rate 40
weapon_rate 40
stream_distance 300.0
stream_rate 1000
```

and after i start my server i have this in my server_log.txt:

```
----------
Loaded log file: "server_log.txt".
----------

SA-MP Dedicated Server
----------------------
v0.3.7-R2, (C)2005-2015 SA-MP Team

[04:35:22] 
[04:35:22] Server Plugins
[04:35:22] --------------
[04:35:22]  Loading plugin: sql.so
```

Server just crashes on Loading plugin: sql.so (sql.so are the first plugin added in server.cfg line plugins)

When i remove line plugins in server.cfg then when I try to run server it says Loading filterscript:blabla and crash just like plugins.

Its very strange for me and I don't know what is the problem here. First I thought it was something I did wrong with a machine but I didnt I bought some server from good hosting few slots to test and same problem. Please help me.

Comment: Post also the log when you remove sql.so.

Answer (score 0):

Download libmysql.dll
Thats a simple fix, nothing else is

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have mysql provided by host and you are trying to connect your server to SQL. Try to get mysql plugin instead of sql.